# Why does this Tintin album not have a printing number?

Tags: french-language, comics, physical-books, tintin, herge

Why does this French Tintin book (*Tintin et les Picaros*) not have a printing number?

[image: Photo of the title verso page of Tintin et les Picaros, copyright 1976]

**Update**:

After talking with someone who lives in France they said to have a look at the bottom of either the first or last page for the *Dépôt légal* date for an idea of when it was released.
[image: bottom of last page]

Comment: Do books printed in France have printing numbers, or is this an English-speaking custom? I don't own enough French books to tell, but judging from the one French book I own that I could easily find, I suspect that in general they may not.

Comment: Editions and reprintings of Tintin albums are hard to date. The copyright year, for example, is not helpful at all. What is needed is a more detailed description and images of the front and back covers, and some who has access to *444 albums Tintin*, a collectors' guide by Luc Brigode.

Comment: @PeterShor During Hergé's lifetime, [Casterman](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casterman) was very much a Belgian publisher, not a French one.

Comment: @PeterShor would you like to ask a general question about printing numbers being present during this period from publishers based out of certain locales?

Comment: @Bobbie: I think that's a good idea. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer%27s_key) only has a page for "printer's key" in Polish and Chinese, and googling images using the Polish term for "printer's key," "Oznaczenie numeru druku," only gives me books in English and German, so I strongly suspect that this method is only used in a few languages, not including French.